# Search one field with Firestore

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I know some people including me usually get all data from Firestore => add array and filter them by name, but loading the whole document is not possible

I've got an idea but I'm not sure if this is possible

I have 2 ways

first:

when adding a product like this

```
product1:{
    name: chicken,
    age: 20
}
product2:{
    name: chicken2,
    age: 20
}
```

After successfully adding we will immediately insert 2 names chicken1 and chicken2 into a Search collection collection

When user searches for names in collectionSearch(can we union name? if yes, that would be better)

Second:

Can Firestore provide a way to separate existing name data into a separate collection, CollectionSearch?

Answer (score 0):

Before I write here I long answer I would rather point you to an [article](https://medium.com/@ken11zer01/firebase-firestore-text-search-and-pagination-91a0df8131ef) I used to build a full text search on a single field.

It explains in detail how to build it from the structure to the usage.

We automated the proccess by creating cloud functions witch generate the `keywoards`. You can use the same method even for multiple fields.